# Ng-repeat is not working if page is loaded dynamicly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this page;

```
<script>
angular.module('myapp', []).controller('categoryCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.category = <? echo json_encode($myarr); ?>;
    $scope.subcategory = <? echo json_encode($myarr2); ?>;
});
</script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="categoryCtrl" id="cate-container">
<div ng-repeat="x in category" class="cate-holder">
<div class="cate-class" onClick="opensubcate(this)">{{x.isim}}</div>
<div class="subcate-holder">
<div ng-repeat="y in subcategory | filter:{kategori:x.isim}" class="subcate-class">{{y.isim}}</div>
</div>

</div>
<div id="list-holder">
</div>
</div>
```

And with ajax i call this page into `#list-holder`.

```
<script>
angular.module('myapplist', []).controller('listCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.list = <? echo json_encode($myarr3); ?>;
});
</script>
<div ng-app="myapplist" ng-controller="listCtrl" id="list-container">
<div ng-repeat="i in list">{{i.isim}}</div>
</div>
```

Everything works great and it is coming with $scope.list is defined with what i got from database. But `ng-repeat="i in list"` is not working and printing `{{i.isim}}` as it is.

If I open the second page directly it prints the outputs of `i.isim`

And the ajax for those who doubt ajax is not working well =)

```
$('.subcate-class').click(function(){
        var thissub = $(this).text();
        var thiscate = $(this).parent('.subcate-holder').prev('.cate-class').text();
        $.ajax({
            url:"php/salelist.php",
            data:{kategori:thiscate,altkategori:thissub},
            type:'POST',
            success: function(e){
                $('#list-holder').html(e);
            }
        });
     });
```

Comment: Uh, where exactly do you use ajax? The data is rendered server-side by PHP and assigned directly to a variable in the $scope

Comment: Ajax is working and there is not problem with getting and assaigning the data into $scope.list variable. in debugging mode i see the JSON data is here but it is not printing the ng-repeat. @JeremyThille

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all. I can see no ajax call in your code whatsoever, and therefore the statement `Ajax is working fine` sounds strange.

Comment: I shared the ajax as well for your doubt =) @JeremyThille

Comment: It is not a good idea the usage of $.ajax in an angular.js app. Use $http service instead.

Comment: I understand what the problem is now but dont know how to solve it. ng-repeat works as onload function but as my page is already loaded and i call it dynamiclly it doesnt perform its for loop for the array. it needs to be fired manually but i dont know how to fire ng-repeat manually in an element. @nicolascolman

Comment: You should learn how to use $apply().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem with a bit of research. The ajax was not the main problem but the main problem was having two `ng-app`. The first one is rendering it-self automaticly but the second one doesnt render on `document onload`. Ajax was not the main problem as tried to predefine `$scope.list` and remove ajax, there was still ng-repeat problem. Then I understand the problem was second `ng-app`. I converted two page format into one page and removed second `ng-app` and put them all into first `ng-app`. Then I decided to use `$http` of angular, instead of `$.ajax` of jquery because there was no way to put `$.ajax` response into angulars `$scope.list`. The final is this;

PS: ng-repeat doesnt need any `$apply` or something because when var change it renders again automaticlly.

```
<script>
angular.module('myapp', []).controller('categoryCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.category = <? echo json_encode($myarr); ?>;
    $scope.subcategory = <? echo json_encode($myarr2); ?>;
    $scope.liste;

    $scope.clickfunc = function(e){
        $scope.thissub = $(e).text();
        $scope.thiscate = $(e).parent('.subcate-holder').prev('.cate-class').text();
        $http({
            method : "POST",
            url : "php/salelist.php",
            params:{kategori:$scope.thiscate,altkategori:$scope.thissub}
        }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
            $scope.liste = response.data.list;
        }, function myError(response) {
            $scope.liste = response.statusText;
        });
        }
});
</script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="categoryCtrl" id="cate-container">
<div ng-repeat="x in category" class="cate-holder">
<div class="cate-class" onClick="opensubcate(this)">{{x.isim}}</div>
<div class="subcate-holder">
<div ng-repeat="y in subcategory | filter:{kategori:x.isim}" class="subcate-class" ng-click="clickfunc($event.target)" onClick="showem()">{{y.isim}}</div>
</div>

</div>

<div id="list-holder">
<div id="list-container">
<div id="back" onClick="goback()">&lt;</div>
<input type="text" ng-model="filterem" id="filterem" placeholder="Ara...">
<table class="urun-table">
<tr><th width="31%"></th><th width="10%">Kategori</th><th width="10%">Altkategori</th><th width="31%">İsim</th><th width="7%">Stok</th><th width="11%">Fiyat</th></tr>
</table>
<div id="table-scroll">
<table class="urun-table">
<tr ng-repeat="i in liste | filter:filterem" class="urun-holder">

<td width="33%"><img src="urun/{{i.resim}}" class="urun-img"></td>
<td width="10%" class="urun-cate">{{i.kategori}}</td>
<td width="10%" class="urun-sub">{{i.altkategori}}</td>
<td width="33%" class="urun-name" onClick="details(this)">{{i.isim}}</td>
<td width="7%" class="urun-price">{{i.stok}}</td>
<td width="7%" class="urun-stock">{{i.fiyat}} TL</td>
<td style="display:none" width="0" class="feed">{{i.feed}}</td>
<td style="display:none" width="0" class="origin">{{i.origin}}</td>
<td style="display:none" width="0" class="feature">{{i.feature}}</td>

</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I see the problem now that you've shared your Ajax call. And *yes*, this Ajax call is the problem.

What you're doing wrong is that you use jQuery and Angular together. Don't do that, ever. These are concurrent technologies that really don't work the same way. Angular generates the DOM from data, jQuery manipulates the DOM. In other words, jQuery fetches your data, but Angular has no idea about it, so it doesn't react and doesn't update the view.

Not to mention that you are loading two libraries instead of one.

Solution : DROP jQuery and do things the Angular way (use the $http service), or DROP Angular and do everything the jQuery's way.

Comment: Ok lemme explain why i use both. First of all both are not used on same page. I have a index page with full Jquery and 2 modular page that uses php to get data from database and angularJS to implement some dynamic and responsive output of the data.(the pages that i shared above). In index page i include the angular page-1 into a div and it works well. Then i added an event listener with jquery and when it is clicked it posts some data to angular page-2 and returns back with it into page-1's div and put it there. I belive i just need to use apply() re-render the ng-repeat function.

Answer (score 0):

pass the php variable values through `ng-init` function and then assign the list.

```
<div ng-app="myapplist" ng-controller="listCtrl" id="list-container"
  ng-init="loadList('<? echo json_encode($myarr3); ?>')">

      <div ng-repeat="i in list">{{i.isim}}</div>
</div>


angular.module('myapplist', []).controller('listCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.list;
    $scope.loadList($scope.list)
});
```

Comment: the php variable is a very very long JSON data. So is this going to be a effective solution?

Comment: don't think the length of the json gonna effect in here

Comment: lemme have a try

Comment: can u create a demo

Comment: I cannot because the data is coming from server database with php :/